# Designing a class with array

Tags: c++

I have a file that contains a list of data something like this:

> 2012-01-01 Rain 7 13 0.28
>
> 2012-01-02 ScatteredClouds 4 8 0.25
>
> 2012-01-03 Rain 6 12 0.28
>
> 2012-01-04 Rain 5 10 0.28
>
> 2012-01-05 Rain 7 12 0.28

---

I have managed to design a class and extract the data into my program. I'm stuck now on designing:

1. how to find the sum of the 3rd column data
2. how to match the year to the other data.

eg: for case #2 - I want to find number of occurrences of 'Rain' in 2012.

P.S: I just started learning programming, sorry if the answer is obvious.

Here's my code:

```
const int SIZE = 2000;

class City
{
 public:
    string date;
    string weatherDesc;
    int minTemp;
    int maxTemp;
    double rainfall;
};

int main( )
{

    City london[SIZE];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("weather.txt");

    int i = 0;
    while ((! fin.eof( )) && (i < SIZE))
    {
        fin >> london[i].date
            >> london[i].weatherDesc
            >> london[i].minTemp
            >> london[i].maxTemp
            >> london[i].rainfall;
        cout << london[i].date << " "
             << london[i].weatherDesc << " "
             << london[i].minTemp << " "
             << london[i].maxTemp << " "
             << london[i].rainfall << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good time to learn a vital programming principle: develop new functionality _in isolation_ as much as possible. You want to iterate over an array and sum something up, so try it with `int[]`. Get that working perfectly before you attempt it with this complex type. For #2, you need a better definition of what you're trying to do. Count "Rain" in 2012? Count "Rain" in any given year? Count occurrences of any given `weatherDesc` in 2012? Count Cities that match a general boolean equation on all fields? Filter an array by year?...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply examine each element in the array and see if each City meets the required conditions.

```
int weatherDescCount(City cities[], int count, string year, string desc)
{
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (cities[i].weatherDesc == desc &&
            cities[i].date.substr(0, 4) == year) {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int sumMinTemp(City cities[], int count)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += cities[i].minTemp;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

At the end of main(), add the following code:

```
cout << sumMinTemp(london, i) << endl;
cout << weatherDescCount(london, i, "2012", "Rain") << endl;
```

It prints 29 and 4 with your sample data, as expected.

Comment: By the way it would be better to use std::vector instead of an array of fixed size.